# Animated navigation drawer indicator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, navigation-drawer

I have a simple question but I'm already a little bit confused. YouTube application and other Google apps already have action bar and drawer like this. When navigation drawer is closed we can see such indicator

[image]

and when navigation drawer is opened, the indicator softy (**with animation**) changing to that

[image]

The question is, how to do the same look and feel of drawer indicator in action bar for **Android 2.x**? Animation needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use android support 7 compat library to have navigation drawer functionality in 2.x versions.
Then you can use android Action bar, but a bit differently, instead of getActionBar() you use getSupportActionBar(). Navigation drawer can be implmented with support library according to example http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: @dexxtr, support 7 compact not works for me in < 4.4 devices, Can you please update some code snippets if it's works for you ? thanks in advance.

Comment: @BipinVayalu but it is working well for me on Android 4.x. I used getSupportActionBar() and everything was ok for Android 2.x and 4.x as well

Comment: @dexxtr, Yeah it's now worked for me, i places HomeAsUpIndicator in style and added drawer sync code in onPostCreated method. Thanks!